# BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.plant/files/image.jpeg:

Tags: android, sqlite, image-processing, file-upload

`your text`
This is an Android Java code for an activity that allows the user to add a plant to a database. The activity includes an EditText to input the plant's name, variety, and height, as well as an ImageView to display an image of the plant. The user can either take a photo using the camera or choose a photo from the gallery. The selected photo is then displayed in the ImageView. When the user clicks on the "Add" button, the plant's information is added to the database.

Have tried InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bmOptions);
but it's useless.

```
Class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_VAR + " TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_HEIGHT + " INTEGER, "+
                COLUMN_TARGET + "DOUBLE "+")";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    void addPlant(String name,String var,int height) throws URISyntaxException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues hhh = new ContentValues();

        hhh.put(COLUMN_NAME,name);
        hhh.put(COLUMN_VAR,var);
        hhh.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT,height);

        String filePath = AddActivity.picpath;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
                // 文件存在，可以进行处理
                String filePath = file.getPath();
        } else {
        // 文件不存在，可能需要恢复文件或者更新应用程序
        }
        //process

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,hhh);
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context," Fail1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
            Toast.makeText(context," Success1 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void updateData(String row_id, String name, String var, String height) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues hh = new ContentValues();

        hh.put(COLUMN_ID,row_id);
        hh.put(COLUMN_NAME,name);
        hh.put(COLUMN_VAR,var);
        hh.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT,height);

        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("imageUri"));
        String filePath = imageUri.getPath();
        //process
        long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,hh,"_id=?",new String[]{row_id});
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context," Fail2 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context," Success2 ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name_input, var_input, height_input;
    TextView text_add_pic;
    ImageView imageView_add;
    Button btn_add;

    //用于在接收返回结果时区分不同的请求。 可以使用任意整数作为请求代码。
    public static final int TAKE_PHOTO = 1;//声明一个请求码，用于识别返回结果
    private static final int SCAN_OPEN_PHONE =2;//相册


    private Uri imageUri;
    public String path = null;
    public static Bitmap bitmap ;
    public static String picpath = null;

    public double target=0;
    public String target_path=null;

    private PopupWindow mPopWindow;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        name_input = findViewById(R.id.name_input);
        var_input = findViewById(R.id.var_input);
        height_input = findViewById(R.id.height_input);
        btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        imageView_add = findViewById(R.id.imageView_add);
        text_add_pic = findViewById(R.id.text_add_pic);
        imageView_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){ showPopupWindow(); }
        });


        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String filePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/image.jpeg";
                Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this, MyDatabaseHelper.class);
                intent.putExtra("fileUri", fileUri);
                startActivity(intent);
                MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(AddActivity.this);
                try {
                    myDB.addPlant(name_input.getText().toString().trim(),var_input.getText().toString().trim(), Integer.parseInt(height_input.getText().toString().trim()));
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showPopupWindow() {
        //设置contentView
        View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(AddActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);
        PopupWindow mPopWindow = new PopupWindow(contentView,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        mPopWindow.setContentView(contentView);
        mPopWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.contextMenuAnim);

        //设置各个控件的点击响应
        @SuppressLint({"MissingInflatedId", "LocalSuppress"}) Button btn_pop_album = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pop_album);
        Button btn_pop_camera = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pop_camera);
        Button btn_pop_cancel = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pop_cancel);

        btn_pop_album.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
        btn_pop_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    openCamera();
                }
            }
        });
        btn_pop_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(AddActivity.this,AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        View rootview = LayoutInflater.from(AddActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        mPopWindow.showAtLocation(rootview, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    }

    private void openGallery(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        //intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_OPEN_PHONE);

    }

    private void openCamera(){
        String imageName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        // 获取FileProvider的authority
        String authority = "com.example.plant.file-provider";

// 获取文件
        File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), imageName + ".jpg");

        photoFile.getAbsoluteFile().mkdirs();
        try//判断图片是否存在，存在则删除在创建，不存在则直接创建
        {
            if(photoFile.exists())
            {
                photoFile.delete();
            }
            boolean a = photoFile.createNewFile();
            Log.e("createNewFile", String.valueOf(a));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // 获取content:// URI
        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, photoFile);

        path = imageUri.getPath();
        Log.e("<7:",imageUri.getPath());

        //使用隐示的Intent，系统会找到与它对应的活动，即调用摄像头，并把它存储
        Intent intent0=new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent0.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent0,TAKE_PHOTO);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ImageView img_result=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_add);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { imageUri.getPath() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("TAG", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });
                //将图片解析成Bitmap对象，并把它显现出来
                    String filePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/image.jpeg";
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    //注意bitmap，后面再decode就会为空
                    try {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picpath);
                    picpath = imageUri.getPath().toString();
                    Log.e("", imageUri.getAuthority());

                    Log.e("picpath",picpath);
                    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath") String fileName = picpath;
                    img_result.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    img_result.invalidate();
                    AddActivity.picpath = picpath;

                }break;
            case SCAN_OPEN_PHONE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    Uri selectImage=data.getData();
                    String[] FilePathColumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectImage,
                            FilePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    //从数据视图中获取已选择图片的路径
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FilePathColumn[0]);
                    picpath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    Log.e("picpath",picpath);
                    cursor.close();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picpath);
                    img_result.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    img_result.invalidate();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: How did you obtain an image uri? And what is the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/TomABdh/Plant/blob/main/main/java/com/example/plant/AddActivity

Comment: https://github.com/TomABdh/Plant/blob/main/main/java/com/example/plant/MyDatabaseHelper

Comment: obtain uri by ContentProvider  ;   /BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.plant/files/image.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: One cannot obtain an uri from a content provider. Again: tell where you got your uri from.

Comment: The showPopupWindow() method creates a PopupWindow that contains three Buttons: btn_pop_album, btn_pop_camera, and btn_pop_cancel. The onActivityResult() method handles the result of the gallery and camera Intents. If the result is OK, it scans the file using MediaScannerConnection and displays the image in the ImageView.

Comment: You did still not post the code where we could see the uri you got or the file path you got. We dont know what you call 'the result of the gallery.  ` Post the code. (Not in a comment).

Comment: This is all my code for uploading images, in addActivity, to pick or take a photo from the camera, from the gallery, and display it to the imageView, but I want to do it in MyDataBaseHelper, No such file or directory is reported at runtime.

Comment: `String filePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/image.jpeg";
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
 ` What do you want with that code? getFilesDir() ?

Comment: The code is to save the image